# What is (! is)?

Tags: c#

I have a similar code:

```cs
if (variable !is AnyType)
{
    // TODO
}
```

But what is that `!is`? It compiles only in C# preview and Rider doesn't show any errors.

Comment: In the context of C#, that is invalid code.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#testing-for-type-compatibility

Comment: To do "if not is", you would have to do `if (!(variable is AnyType))`

Comment: But my JetBrains Rider tells me it's completely fine. :thinking: okay

Comment: Rider says that is OK code in a .cs file?

Comment: [tag:fubo] I asked what is !is and whether it's correct rather than how to negate the is.

Comment: I will try to compile it rn, cuz JetBrains tells it's all ok

Comment: but [tag:fubo] i dont need the valid positive and negative. You misunderstand. lol. I need to know what is !is and why is it correct (at least JB tells me so)

Comment: It **isn't** correct. Now, the *syntax highlighter* in Rider doesn't seem to indicate that this is invalid code, but the compiler does, and it *is* invalid.

Comment: @IvMisticos this should not compile.  And JB Rider should be throwing an error if this is in a .cs file.  If it's not then something is wrong with your environment.

Comment: no its all fine with my environment idk why is it so, will try to compile and see

Comment: No, he's actually right in that Rider does not *indicate* that this is invalid code. I just tested it. It doesn't compile though and it *is* invalid. This seems to be a bug in the C# parser used for the syntax highlighting.

Comment: @IvMisticos your code is just wrong and there doesn't exit something like `!is` it doesn'T even compile

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I just tested it myself, that is odd.  Seems to just be a bug in Rider/Resharper

Comment: The feature 'nullable reference types' is currently in Preview and *unsupported*. To use Preview features, use the 'preview' language version.

Comment: So in fact i guess it is valid but only for preview and it is not negative for is.

Comment: Yes, in preview it compiles.

Comment: Ah, so this is not `!is`, this is `variable! is AnyType`.

Comment: yeah. lol  \ (:) /

Comment: Just because I can't resist... it depends on what your definition of `is` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your comments you say this is Rider not telling you that it is invalid.

However, it *is* invalid code. You will not be able to compile C# code using this construct.

However, it also seems that Rider doesn't *indicate* that this is invalid code:

[image: Rider rendering code]

It should add "squigglies" beneath the code, like in this example:

[image: Rider rendering other code]

So this seems to be a bug in the parser that handles syntax highlighting and validation.

Regardless of this, the code *is* invalid, and does not compile:

[image: Build errors]

---

<strike>Judging from lv Misticos' (now deleted) answer, this may be legal code in C# 8 preview, but right now it is invalid.</strike>

OK, now it became clear.

In C# 8 preview, the ! is not associated with the `is` operator, it is associated with the variable, so what you have is understood as this:

```
if (variable! is AnyType)
```

Let me rephrase that in pseudo-code:

```
if (variable /* that isn't null, honestly, just trust me*/ is AnyType)
```

So yes, this is in fact going to be legal C# code if all plans for C# 8 come to fruition.

I guess JetBrains have added support for syntax highlighting of C# 8 things ahead of time. I still say it is some form of bug in Rider though, they shouldn't allow future C# syntax until it is actually supported. For instance, I do not have C# 8 or any such preview installed so the latest C# Rider is able to use on my PC is 7.3 (I think).